# Eclipse with ADT instead of Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have the following problem, Google had stopped the support for ADT and Eclipse and recommends to use Android Studio. I try this option but Android Studio needs **too much resources so my computer hangs up**.

Despite the recommendations, I have tried to install the ADT plugin with eclipse and an unsupported version of the Android SDK. But if I tried to build a project I got errors like **"error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'"**

I found out that installing the Android Support Library solves this error but there is no package provided by my version of the Android SDK. Also after hours I haven't succeeded to run/build an Android application with eclipse and ADT!

Finally, my question: Is it still possible to develop Android Apps with eclipse (or any other IDE than Android Studio) with official Google support?

Comment: You don't need Android Studio to build your APK. You can use any IDE including Notepad or vi, and build on command line with `./gradlew :assembleNormalDebug`.

Comment: Okay I checked out the command line tools for Android Development with gradle, is there any plugin to integrate these tools convenient to eclipse or can I use the standart gradle plugin of eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use the legacy plugin. I know, google is very strict in their marketingplans, but if you get this working its only a temporal solutions for only a few release versions. Intellij is a very good ide in my opinion. When google starts first level support for such a powerful environment, i would recommend to spend some money in new hardware. Especially when its for free.

Comment: I tried Intellij and found out that this is the reason of my performance problems, all my other software and IDEs run perfectly on my current hardware so I won't accept to buy new hardware with Android Studio as the only reason